# Restrict access to AD application, using AD group via Azure Portal

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, active-directory-group

Inside of my Azure Active Directory setup, I have the following:

Groups:

- An AD group for my application (with several users in it)

App Registrations:

- An AD application for my SPA

I want to restrict access to this SPA (AD app) to only users in the AD group I created for my application.

At the moment, anyone in my org can log in to the SPA.
I don't want this.

How can I prevent people outside of this AD group (but still in my org) from logging in to my AD app?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users) to restrict Azure AD applications to a group of users in an Azure AD tenant.